# Save contour to image

Tags: python, opencv

I used `cv2.findContours` to find objects and after processing I want to save certain contour(s). I must first create empty image and then use `cv2.drawContours` command. However docstring for this command is following:

```
drawContours(image, contours, contourIdx, color[, thickness[,lineType[, hierarchy[, maxLevel[, offset]]]]]) -> None
```

and `contourIdx` is required, while I have no idea what is it supposed to be.

Does anyone know how to get this parameter, or even demonstrate other way of dumping contours to file?

---

**Update**:

for dumping single contour `contourIdx` parameter should be set to `-1`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work.

```
drawing = np.zeros(img.shape)
for i in xrange(len(contours)):
    if (cv2.contourArea(contours[i]) > 15000): # just a condition
        cv2.drawContours(drawing, contours, i, (255, 255, 255), 1, 8, hierarchy)
```

Comment: I already updated my question with solution, but I'll mark your answer as correct in global case for drawing all contours.